# How can I use quartz instead of x11 on these terminal commands?

Tags: ssh, terminal, x11, quartz-graphics

I am trying to ssh into a remote Linux server using x11. I found that Mountain Lion no longer supports x11 when I upgraded, so I installed Quartz. However, my terminal commands are not working anymore. Here are two important terminal commands that no longer work for me.

I did a Google search and looked elsewhere on Stack Overflow, but didn't find what I am looking for. Namely, I was hoping there are some new commands that work with Quartz in place of the standard x11 phrases I have been using. I tried these after I installed Quartz on my machine, and it didn't work. I just taught myself these x11 commands on 10.7 when 10.8 just came out. Here are a few examples.

1.

```
ssh -X username@serverlocation.com
```

2.

```
./configure -- this/is/an/example/directory --enable--gdb --with-x -with-x11 --with-term --with-nogui
```

If anyone could tell me how to get this working with Quartz on Mountain Lion, I would be grateful. Otherwise, I would have to run a VM on my Mac with either Windows and putty in, or try to figure out how to use x11 on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you logged out/in after installing XQuartz? XQuartz is just a distribution of X11 and is completely compatible with what was previously included with the OS X.

Comment: I didn't log out, I restarted the machine.

Comment: Strange. What happens if you run `X` in terminal?

Comment: When I used the ssh -X command, quartz X appears. So that seems to have "fixed" itself after two reboots. However, when I run the second example command. It gives an error which says "x11 not present".

Comment: Oh, now I understand. XQuartz installs itself to /opt instead of usual location in /usr. So its includes will be at /opt/X11/include. You have to add an option to your configure command line to search for includes in this additional location.

Comment: So instead of -with-x11, I write -with-/opt/X11/include?

Comment: No.. Try `CFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include ./configure <...>` or you will have to read output of `./configure --help` to find out how to specify additional include paths.

Comment: That worked. But I ran into more problems later on. I also figured out that there seems to be an issue with X11 forwarding with Mountain Lion and my Linux server. I am going to consider this answered, but if you have ideas on how to fix forwarding with xQuartz on ML, please let me know.

Comment: Haven't used forwarding for a long time, sorry.